# Internet connected ,but cant reach any site

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, networking

- internet connected but cant reach any site after installing new windows on my laptop .
- this morning i was working normally ,after the new windows
  connected to internet ,but no app can reach any internet or the edge .

  - edge error message :
    **Hmmm... can't reach this page** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your computer may not have taken an IP address
open the windows command prompt and type ***ipconfig*** and check if there are any IP addresses, if there are none, type ***ipconfig /release***, then ***ipconfig /renew*** and then ***ipconfig /flushdns***
if there is still no IP address, try restarting your router